# Three20 TTLauncher and TTTableItem seem to push views differently?

Tags: iphone, xcode, three20

When I use the TTLauncher to call a TTTableViewController the table is loaded correctly it shows the "Loading..." screen as expected and then the table:

```
- (void)launcherView:(TTLauncherView*)launcher didSelectItem:(TTLauncherItem*)item {
 [[TTNavigator navigator] openURLAction:[TTURLAction actionWithURLPath:item.URL]];  
}
```

However when I call the TTTableViewController from a TTTableSubtitleItem using the URL:

```
[TTTableSubtitleItem itemWithText:@"Locations Map" subtitle:@"Find a specific location"       URL:@"tt://BuildingsLocationTableViewController/Loc"]
```

the loading screen does NOT show, it waits and then goes directly to the loaded table. Can anyone tell me why these call the TTTableViewController is different ways considering they both map through TTURLMap?

Thanks

JC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mechanism, as you say, is just the same in both cases.

I would suggest checking your `BuildingsLocationTableViewController` model definition, and check the `isLoading`selector, and the data source `titleForLoading` selector.

From there, if you debug, you should be able to find out a little more.

Comment: Hi, its seems the problem happens when i call the view with initWithName instead of initWithNibName. I have to call this view with initWithName so I can pass in a parameter using:                       [map from:@"tt://VideoListViewController/(initWithName:)" toViewController: [VideoListViewController class]];

Comment: If you need more help (sorry, it is not clear), could you paste in your main question the map definition for the controllers at play here and possibly also the `initWithName` implementation?